# Using VB.net to get Excel Cell Value which is not the correct value?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, debugging, vba

I've been stuck on this for the past few hours so I really could do with some help. I am trying to get numeric (integer and decimal) values from an Excel spreadsheet and use it create a graph on my form using the chart control or even display that value in a textbox.

The Value of cell A11 is "2003" and K11 is "12.00" but the returned values are 0 and 12. I use formulas to calculate the rest of the y values. The strange thing is that text works fine. Cell A3 has "initial" which comes back as "initial", it's just the numbers which don't work.

```
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\File.xls")    
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("C:\File.xls")
    xlSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim x1 As String
    Dim y1 As String
    x1 = xlSheet.Range("A11").Value.ToString     
    y1 = xlSheet.Range("K11").Value.ToString
    MsgBox(x1)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the "number format" of these cells? Are you changing this property from your application?

Comment: The number format for the cell is general for x and number for y

Comment: This is certainly weird. There might be problems with special formats but "general" tends to work well (perhaps to make completely sure you should hardcode the numberformat to text: .NumberFormat = "@"). Don't know what might be the problem, I would need to test the specific conditions.

Comment: I realised my own mistake...I had selected the wrong excel sheet! Arggh!

Comment: This sounds a bit more logical :) No big deal, everyone makes mistakes. This will surely help you to not repeat this mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.Text` instead of `.Value`. It will retrieve the value shown instead of the cell value:

```
x1 = xlSheet.Range("A11").Text
y1 = xlSheet.Range("K11").Text
```

This will ignore even the formats, for example, the value `7.7777` in a cell with a format to show 2 decimal places will show `7.78`, and that is what `.Text` will retrieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply SysDragon. Using .text improves it but it still returns 0 for x1 when it should be 2300. y1 returns 12.00 though.

Comment: "This will ignore even the formats" is not true. it might show a different behaviour but will not ignore all the formats. For example: if you type a number (123) into a cell with a date format, you would get the date (not the number) with both options (.Text and .Value).

Comment: @varocarbas That is what I say. You would get the displayed value of everything, with `.Text`.

Comment: ?! Perhaps I didn't explain the point properly: if you type 222 in a cell with a date format (mm/dd/yyyy) and you don't consider the format, you should get 222. What I said is that in that case you would get the same with .Value and .Text, that is, the corresponding date: 1/1/1999 (random date), not the actually-input value (222). Thus, your statement "This will ignore even the formats" is wrong. In any case, this answer was clearly not addressing the problem here: .Value should have output everything perfectly under the conditions described by the OP.

Comment: @varocarbas Maybe "ignore" was not the right word. Obviously I meant to say (there is even an example!) that you get the displayed values, thus being totally a possible right solution for the problem, since he was getting a different value that displayed.

Comment: From your statement I understand that the difference between .Text and .Value is that the first one ignores the formats, what is not true. If you consider that this is not what is transmitted in this sentence, just don't change it. BUT your answer didn't address the problem. There is no a single scenario where for two numeric values (2003 and 12.00) .Value delivers something completely off (0) and .Text not. There might be some issues with roundings + format but this is not what 2003 into zero meant. The problem was clearly somewhere else.

Comment: @varocarbas No way! It could totally be a nice try to solve a possible problem in that scenario. We don't know all the things that are happening in the sheet (like happened with a issue not presented). I don't even know the formats used in the cells at the moment I post the answer.

Comment: You are free to think that you can stop wars with your smile. And will seriously be really nice to see this work. But the reality is that your chances of accomplishing such a thing are below 10 to the power of -9999999999. .Value and .Text deliver the same thing. If the format of the cell has certain configuration of decimals, .Text might ignore it. There is no configuration of decimals, rounding, numeric types (integer, double, float, etc.), nothing allowing to mistake a 2003 with 0. The only option you would have to get a different result by using .Text or .Value on such a scenario...

Comment: ... would be the same chances of stopping the aforementioned war with your smile (one of the electronic components of the given computer fails under very specific situations making such a situation possible). With the provided information (2003 into 0) and without knowing anything else, there is no (sensible, probable and expectable) way in which .Text will deliver something different than .Value. If value delivers 0, .Text has to deliver 0. In any case, if you would have needed further information regarding formatting (to be completely and absolutely sure) you should have asked it.

Comment: But this is just my opinion (equivalently to "This will ignore even the formats" should be removed to avoid misunderstandings) feel free to continue thinking in your way.

Comment: @varocarbas Calm down! All your (our) comments should be removed too, since you're not provinding anything helpful and only discussing with your opinion. And you don't have any need to be so rude and ridiculize my answer and my opinion. Im removing this later on.

Comment: Ridiculize? Rude? I have just been passionate (and kind of funny) in my argumentation I am completely relaxed. Why I am not providing anything helpful? You are saying that it makes sense and I am justifying you why it doesn't. The logical output from this conversation would have been you accepting that your answer needs some teawking to avoid misunderstandings. You keep defending that was motivated, I keep defending that it wasn't. I don't see the rudeness. Some people (quite a few from our country) considers that discussing openly about things is rude. I don't think in this way.

Comment: See the conversation with the OP for inspiration regarding what I consider more normal: the OP did a mistake and instead spending time in intending to come with a crazy justification explaining that he didn't really make any mistake (I am not saying that you are doing that; just that, under these conditions, this would have been the behaviour of quite a few of our paisanos), he just said "my bad, sorry". No problem. End of the situation. I suggested you something, you can take it on board or not (end). But you decided to keep intending to prove that it was logical... no end (neither rudeness).

Comment: @varocarbas This is not the place to discuss your opinions

Comment: Regarding paisanos? This is just a half-jokish reference (every time I talk generally is half-joking). I have been discussing about your code and lately about your attitude. I don't think that a person not wanting to get any kind of feedback and focusing on what he (she... not sure) said/did was right no matter what is something which is irrelevant to SO. In any case, the whole point of continuing is letting clear (for future readers) that there is no difference between .Value and .Text (no one relevant under these conditions). Refer this in your answer and will delete all the comments.